# Web app to compile java code

Tags: java

I see many Java online tests can run even if java is not installed on my computer (e.g, https://codility.com/). Does this type of systems send the code to the back-end to compile or there is a way to compile the code on the browser? Thanks.

Comment: _send the code to the back-end to compile_ Yes, they send code to back end to compile and NO they won't compile the code on browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working of online compiler is not different from a compiler installed in your desktop.

Usually online compiles support multiple programming language.

Online compilers are hosted on a server which are usually exposed to the clients through web page.  Using web page these online compiler takes code and programming language as input and based on the programming language server selects the appropriate compiler and compile the input code using that compiler. It is the job of server to parse the result of compilation and publish result to the client who submitted the compilation request.